# Are there any downsides to using "apt" on the raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, linux, apt

I normally use `apt-get` on the raspberry pi to update/install/etc., but I like just plain `apt` better because of the better interface and text coloring, etc. I can't seem to find anything on google that says you *shouldn't* use apt for raspberry pi, but all the raspberry pi tutorials and documentation all use `apt-get`.

I know on other Linux dists(like ubuntu) `apt` is used much more often, so why do all the raspberry pi tutorials use `apt-get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between Raspbian and other Debian distributions belonging to use `apt`. The Raspberry Pi is intended to be used by beginners and I suppose there are more beginners for Linux than in other distros. The Raspberry Pi Foundation seems to be a little bit conservative so most official documentation on [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) uses old style system tools like `apt-get` vs. `apt` and `ifconfig` vs. `iproute2` or `iwconfig` vs. `iw` and so on. Beginners copy and paste that and so we have this situation.

I suggest to use modern system tools like `apt`, `iproute2`, `iw` or `systemd` because old tools like `net-tools` with `ifconfig` and friends become deprecated by the time.